# When learning ethical web hacking, should I learn javascript, html, or both

Tags: javascript, html, ctf

I am learning ethical hacking, mostly with websites. I know the basics of the web but what coding language should I learn first when it comes to website hacking. I want it to help me in not only ctf but in real instances.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding HTML and being able to manipulate it to your advantage will be important, as well as being able to interpret what some javascript code is doing. I recommend looking into both as they will both aid you.

You should also be sure to use the developer tools your browser provides you with to your advantage; Google Chrome and similar browsers provide many useful tools such as the network tab, console and source inspector within their developer tools. These can be useful in certain cases, especially where it may not be extremely clear what you must do to exploit a website.

In terms of using knowledge of web hacking for real world uses, I recommend not focusing solely on the client side. You certainly should spend some time learning about the server side. Looking into key concepts regarding programming security, such as input validation will be very useful.

Having an understanding of things such as input validation can lead into being able to perform SQL injection attacks; you should definitely look into SQL injection, as well as command injection, but ensure you are comfortable manipulating HTML and understanding javascript before moving on to this. Grasping these concepts will not only allow you to exploit these vulnerabilities, but also allow you to ensure you have protected any software you write against them.

I recommend having a look at https://overthewire.org/wargames/natas/natas0.html to train your skills and give you good way to actively learn these concepts.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Well said. Knowing both will never hurt. Knowing and having strong experience in multiple languages will only improve your hacking ability.